# Update table value to null thru API in Oracle PL/SQL EBS

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-ebs

I'm trying to set value of fnd_user.password_lifespan_days to null thru fnd_user_pkg.UpdateUser API. I'm not able to set null value by using this API, because it keeps value the same and not changing it to NULL.

I tried to use fnd_api.G_NULL_NUM but I'm keep getting the errors like "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: number precision too large" or "ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column".

Is there any way to change fnd_user.password_lifespan_days value to null thru APIs'? Because I'm not supposed to use a simple Update to change it.

Comment: Why do you need to set it to NULL? If you don't want it to expire try 365250. In a 100 years time it will catch up with you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the function fnd_user_pkg.null_number to set numeric parameters to null